# Start and position powershell window from cmd

Tags: powershell

I am starting several powershell (version 5) windows from a batch file and would like to position them when starting them.

This is what I use to start the powershell from cmd:

`start powershell -NoExit -Command "Get-Content .\MyLog.txt -tail 10 -wait | Select-String 'Search term' | timestamp"`

The "start" command only gives the option to start a new window maximised or minimised (`min` and `max`).

I am looking to position my window using x and y coordinates, eg. `-X 1911 -Y 12`.

I have found several solution but they seem to be tailored to be run from a powershell rather than a batch file (eg. [Set the position of Powershell window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61231739/set-the-position-of-powershell-window))

Any ideas?

Comment: Please review the output from `START /?`. Please describe in what way this does not do what is needed. See http://stackoverflow.com/help for more information about how to ask good questions.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70646045/open-powershell-from-cmd-and-use-filter-problem-with-escaping?noredirect=1#comment124886830_70646045?

Comment: I am curious to know what about the answer you linked did not work and why do this? 
@lit gave a helpful link. Reorganize your question.

Comment: Thanks @lit - I added my inputs directly in the question, hope this is better?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - nope, the one you linked was about adding a filter and not to position a window.